# Very Simple ng-include not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I need to perform a very simple " ng-include ", and I cannot get this working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the part I want help with

```
<div class="slide-animate" ng-include="'template1.html'"></div>
```

I have used the single quotes as mentioned elsewhere. And, I have no idea why this is not working. Could it be the initialisation of the Angular framework ? Could it be any other conflicting feature in the code ?

Any  Here is the full code.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-example83-production</title>
    <style>
    .slide-animate-container {
        position:relative;
      background:white;
      border:1px solid black;
      height:40px;
      overflow:hidden;
}

.slide-animate {
  padding:10px;
}

.slide-animate.ng-enter, .slide-animate.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;

  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
}

.slide-animate.ng-enter {
  top:-50px;
}
.slide-animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  top:0;
}

.slide-animate.ng-leave {
  top:0;
}
.slide-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  top:50px;
}

  </style>


  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script>

      (function(angular) {
          alert("hello");
angular.module('includeExample', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.templates =
      [ { name: 'template1.html', url: 'template1.html'},
        { name: 'template2.html', url: 'template2.html'} ];
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
    $scope.name = "World";
  }]);
})(window.angular);

  </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="includeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
         <option value="">(blank)</option>
      </select>
      url of the template: <code>{{template.url}}</code>
      <p>Hello, {{name}}! </p>
      <div class="slide-animate-container">
            <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="'template1.html'"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ng-include makes the XHR call so if you are working with file server then it will not work and it worked in server because the server is capable of handling the HTTP . you can create a simple web server using Grunt plugin https://github.com/devpaul/grunt-devserver .

Answer (score 1):

@popovitsj Sorry for the trouble. Found out that when I upload the website to the server, it works. I was working on localhost before and it doesn't work there. No idea why though.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: templates make a http call if it is server from the file :// then it wont work .

Comment: Thanks so much satish ! Dint realise that I had been working on files, I did not have the localhost switched on. I can mark your answer the correct one if you post it as a Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and it does in fact work. So the problem must lie somewhere outside of the code you posted.

Perhaps the file template1.html does not exist, or is at least not in the same directory?

Comment: The file template1.html exists in the same directory. I was able to check the URL in the browser also. Does it have anything to do with how AngularJs is setup ? I am using grunt to work with it. 

And btw, thanks for the reply. Dint notice your reply or I would I replied back much earlier.